# Java run time error.missing static main method

Tags: java

https://github.com/joywang1994/question2/blob/master/test2.java

This is my code. It has a run time error which says I don't have a static main method
Why? How could I fix it?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Show us the complete error message and stacktrace, and show us how you are running the code.  The problem is something to do with either the class naming or the way you are running it.

Comment: Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].

Comment: You naming file as test2.java, though the name of the class is `public class HuffmanCode`. Why isn't the compiler complaining, much before, as `public class should be saved in a file with the same name, as that of the class`!!!!!!

Comment: Of course I am using the same name of the class. I copied my code on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are running wrong class file to start the program. I create 3 class file with the name HuffmanTree,HuffmanNode and Huffmancode. Copying it from your GITHUB.  I ran Huffmancode class file. Program compile and runs with out error. I dont have C:\eclipse\Programmes\Datastructure\infix.dat this file so i got file not found exception. Ignoring that my main method called without any trouble.

Comment: Thank you! by the way, how to choose the file I want to run?

Comment: Select file which has public static void main(String[] args) method in it.  In this case it was Huffmancode class has that method.

Comment: Do you mean I cant write all the source code in one java source file?

Comment: if you are using IDE its better to have a separate file. If you are not using IDE . Compile all  the java file then you could see <ClassName>.class then run the class file having main method like  java <Classname>

Comment: Coder please accept the answer if your problem is solved so that this question will not display in unaswered question section

Comment: Thank you. Im not sure how to do this because Im a beginner of this website

Answer (score 0):

If the message is:

> Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].

then it follows that you are (somehow) running the wrong class.  But unless you show us the complete stacktrace, **and** explain how you are running the code, we cannot tell you what you are doing wrong.